Characterization of completeness by total-boundedness.
Some time ago our Functional Analysis professor stated (without proof) a theorem characterizing the completeness of metric spaces where one of the conditions was precisely 'complete and totally bounded'.
Obviously it is ridiculous, but I imagine that some important theorem must have crossed his mind.
Since he is not the most accessible person, I wanted to ask here about characterizations of completeness in relation to precisely this condition.
Greetings and thanks in advance.

Maybe you misremembered. You may be thinking of the characterization of compactness instead.
A metric space is compact if and only if it is complete and totally bounded.
